# how to add new languages into Django? My language "Uyghur" or "Uighur" is not supported in Django

Tags: django, locale

how to add new languages into Django?  My language "Uyghur" or "Uighur" is not supported in Django.

Can I add new language locale file in my project and use it?
for example: zh_UG

this language is not supported in Django.

Comment: I think you can contribute to its repository. Srart converting now.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is right answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Add a non available language to your Django app**

ISO language code of Uighur ئۇيغۇر تىلى is 'ug'.

In your **settings.py**:

```
from django.conf import global_settings

gettext_noop = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
       ('ug', gettext_noop('Uighur')),
)

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ug': {
        'bidi': True, # right-to-left
        'code': 'ug',
        'name': 'Uighur',
        'name_local': u'\u0626\u06C7\u064A\u063A\u06C7\u0631 \u062A\u0649\u0644\u0649', #unicode codepoints here
    },
}

# Add custom languages not provided by Django
import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO

# Languages using BiDi (right-to-left) layout
LANGUAGES_BIDI = global_settings.LANGUAGES_BIDI + ["ug"]
```

And:

```
manage.py makemessages -l ug
manage.py compilemessages
```

Comment: I followed the answer above.  It now stops complaining of new lang (e.g. 'lo') that I added but somehow it gives a wrong link localhost:8000/en/lo   instead of 
localhost:8000/lo
even though when a mouse is hovered over the language button, it shows localhost:8000/lo/ link.   While other language buttons (languages supported by Django) are working fine.  Any suggestion pls. Thank you

Comment: Got it working now.  To stop it from auto changing localhost:8000/lo/ to localhost:8000/en/lo/, i have to add the custom language to django.conf.locale too in addition to my own app.

Comment: i got error "invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION" for ms (malay)

Comment: @laffuste can you take a look at this question pleas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708626/how-to-add-new-language-to-django-settings

Answer (score 12):

Based on laffuste's answer.
First step, add language define in settings.py:

```
EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ms': {
        'bidi': False, # right-to-left
        'code': 'ms',
        'name': 'Bahasa Melayu',
        'name_local': u'Bahasa Melayu', #unicode codepoints here
    },
}

# Add custom languages not provided by Django
import django.conf.locale
from django.conf import global_settings
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items() + EXTRA_LANG_INFO.items())
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO

# Languages using BiDi (right-to-left) layout
global_settings.LANGUAGES = global_settings.LANGUAGES + (("ms",'Bahasa Melayu'),)
```

Second step, Add locale in settings.py:

```
import os

PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'locale'),
)
```

Third step, Add locale defines in locale directory.

Answer (score 4):

If someone encounters this, and will use the accepted answer (also check the comments on it) and still will have a redirect to /en/ instead of extra language - you need to create the .mo file for that locale. At least a dummy one.

Django checks if language is valid by checking if it can load the .mo file. There is no issue for standard languages because Django is shipped with a bunch of them, but for your custom language it doesn't exists.

I hope that will save your time.

Answer (score 2):

in your settings.py add

```
gettext = lambda s: s


LANGUAGES = (
    ('zh_UG', gettext('Uyghur')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)
USE_I18N = True
```

run

```
manage.py makemessages -l zh_UG
```

to create language files

Comment: When I was adding my language to a Django-powered website, I had also to add it to django.conf.locale, otherwise was getting "Unknown language code" error.

Comment: Will this also work as a sublanguage? i.e. will zh_UG be viewed as a sublanguage of zh?

Answer (score 1):

```
# add Kyrgyz lang 
###########################################################
from django.conf import global_settings
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext('Russia')),
    ('ky', gettext('Kyrgyz')),
)
EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ky': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ky',
        'name': 'Kyrgyz',
        'name_local': u"Кыргызча",
    },
}

import django.conf.locale
from django.conf import global_settings
import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
global_settings.LANGUAGES = global_settings.LANGUAGES + [("ky", 'Кыргызча')]

import os
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
###########################################################
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer how it is different from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that you need to run below commands despite whether you have added some translation to the files or not:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l tj
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Note that tj here is the new added language

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

Django 5.0 added support for the Uyghur language ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/5.0/#internationalization))!