# adding a custom language to django

Tags: python, django, multilingual

I'm translating my website into the 24 languages of the European Union. These include the "Malti" language, that is not listed in django default supported languages.

I would like to know if there is a way to add a custom language to django so it can work with the native i18n url function.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su

Comment: Are you asking how to add a new translation to Django itself (for example Django admin panel) or how to add Malti locale to your website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I found the solution, you have to manually add a folder in /django/conf/locale/ with the language extension you want. Actually you can just copy past the en (english) folder and name it after the missing language (in my case mt).
2. In this folder you can also edit the file formats.py to localize the dates, numbers etc.
3. Restart django and your language will be natively supported.