# i18n of django app to a language "not" listed in LANGUAGE_CODE

Tags: python, django

I found out that in django LANGUAGE_CODE, `et` stands for `Estonian`; I was expecting it would stand for `Ethiopian`, the language that I am trying to internationalize my app to. My question is, how do I go on internationalizing a django app to a language not listed here?

```
>>> from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES
>>> langs = LANGUAGES
>>> for a in langs:
...   print(a)
...
('af', 'Afrikaans')
('ar', 'Arabic')
('az', 'Azerbaijani')
('bg', 'Bulgarian')
('be', 'Belarusian')
# many more results
('et', 'Estonian')
#some more results
```

I am using `Django 1.6.5` on Windows 7 with `Python34`

For the curious ones, here is what Ethiopic font example.

> አበበ በሶ በላ ለቁርስ ዩሁን ምሣ እግዜር ይወቀው::

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add new languages into Django? My language "Uyghur" or "Uighur" is not supported in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has already been answered here:

[adding a custom language to django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267886/adding-a-custom-language-to-django)

I guess you're translating to Amharic language? So maybe the language code `am` would be convenient.

Comment: Thanks @Leistungsabfall. Yea,I am Translating to both Amharic and Tigrigna, they use almost similar font."geez" may be a convenient code.