# Add custom language for localization in Django app

Tags: python, django, web-applications, localization, internationalization

[adding a custom language to django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267886/adding-a-custom-language-to-django)

I checked this question and did all the steps mentioned in the accepted answer. After doing all when I go to `/kjv/` then it redirects to `/en/kjv/`

Project structure:

`MyProject
---------locale 
-------------kjv
-----------------LC_MESSAGES
--------------------django.mo
--------------------django.po
---------myproject
--------------settings.py
---------app
---------manage.py`

Some one can help me to fix this?

settings.py

```
...

import django.conf.locale

gettext = lambda s: s

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'kjv': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': u'kjv',
        'name': u'Kjvx',
        'name_local': u'Kjvx'
    },
}

# Add custom languages not provided by Django
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items() + EXTRA_LANG_INFO.items())
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
LANGUAGES = (
    ('hr', gettext('hr')),
    ('en', gettext('en')),
    ('de', gettext('de')),
    ('fr', gettext('fr')),
    ('kjv', gettext('kjv')),
)
...
```

Django-1.6.5 and all urls are wrapped in `i18n_patterns`.

Comment: do you know if this approach works for newer versions of Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone come to this place  and facing similar issue then don't forget to update/add LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py

e.g

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../locale'),
)
```

You can point to anywhere, given they exist and have valid locale structure.