# How to translate default Django admin panel to another language?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use the default Django admin panel with jazzmin. I need the entire admin panel to be completely in Turkmen language. As far as I know, it is not supported in Django yet. How can I translate the entire admin panel to Turkmen?

I tried to include these:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.index_title = "SmartLib"
admin.site.site_header = "SmartLib Dolandyryş"
admin.site.site_title = "Dolandyryş"
```

But it is not enough. I need to translate everything.

I also tried `makemessages` and `compilemessages` but they didn't generate .po files from the admin panel.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please check the following questions, if the answers help: [adding a custom language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19267886/21350362), ["Uighur" is not supported in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12946830/21350362), [change Django admin language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21469470/21350362), [new site language in Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74370833/21350362)