# Django how to make every view accept a kwarg?

Tags: django

I have a lot of apps running on my site and I was wanting to make all the views accept a certain kwarg without having to go in and edit them all manually? Is there a way to do this?

I suppose I should add it into the django base view class somewhere, but I am unsure exactly where to add it to in that?

Any ideas?

EDIT:

What I am trying to do is have translations set in my db under a certain model and then have the site default text areas be displayed in a certain language based on the url...

```
/eng/some/url
/esp/some/url
```

those two urls would display different languages, but I have to capture the variable and put it into each and every view which is quite cumbersome

Comment: Where do you want to use this kwarg? In the template? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Two things: 

1. you say you want all the views to accept a certain kwarg but then you talk about doing a change in a model so it's not clear where (model or view) you need a kwarg
2. I think it would be easier to help if you would describe what you need the kwarg for, so that if a more django-native solution is available it can be shown to you

Comment: I did mean view and not model, I misspoke. I have fixed the wording and added a more concise explanation. Thanks

Comment: Maybe a middleware would work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django already has some i18n support in urls, [check it out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n). You need to activate `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` by adding it to your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and to tune your urlconf a bit by wrapping your urls with `i18n_patterns`.

The complete example is given in the docs, I see no sense copying it here.

Comment: I see. I think I will have to switch my project to this way of doing it now. One thing that is bothering me a bit is the language codes that Django uses. I built a lot of my project around ISO-639-2 codes which are 3 letter language codes...('eng,' instead of 'en') Do you hvae any idea where I can change this in Django?

Comment: I believe it's quite possible. I think you should start with the [`settings.LANGUAGES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#languages), see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su).

Comment: it took a while, but I converted my whole site to use the proper way of i18n, thanks

Comment: I'm sure it worth the time.