# Adding languages dynamically through Django Admin

Tags: django, internationalization

If I have a project which is using english language and I have all the string fields with translator helpers like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

But I have potential users from other languages (which I dont know which languages are yet). Is it possible to add a new language like french, russian, etc from django admin without modifying django settings and adding the language there?

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal I think that question is about adding a new language, not yet available in Django. This question asks about extending a website and dynamically adding further languages with available translations in Django.