# how to add a language in Django that its not supported by default?

Tags: python, django, translation

Im trying to make a website in 5 languages. The main language should be kurdish but it is not supported by Django default. I tried already the [how to add new languages into Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su/)

but it didnt work for me. I receive an error mesagge

```
**LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items() + EXTRA_LANG_INFO.items())
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'**

I also tried already to copy an english **po file** and rename it "ku" (kurdish) and i added into django/conf/**init**.py the language info.

```
'ku': {
    'bidi': False,
    'code': 'ku',
    'name': 'Kurdish',
    'name_local': 'Kurdî',
},
```

I can see the language by languages option by template but when i click it i receive an error message.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 91, in _tokenize
raise ValueError('invalid token in plural form: %s' % value)
```

ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

Does anybody know how can i fix it?
Thanks so much!

Comment: I urgently need help for this problem.
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

in your settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ku'
LANGUAGES = [('en', 'English'), ('ku', 'Kurdish')]
```

add  `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` in your settings.MIDDLEWARE

Add LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py, this is where your translation files will be stored:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'locale/'),
)
```

Enable i18N

```
USE_I18N = True
```

in *settings.TEMPLATES* add

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
```

in urls.py add

```
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

then in the template you will have let's say 'Hello world'

you must load il18n

```
{% load i18n %}
<p>{% trans "cîhana hello" %}</p>
```

then in the console you must make the messages, it will take all strings with the tag trans and place it in your locale folder

```
./manage.py makemessages -l en #you will translate it to en since your default language is 'ku'
```

And now all is left is to go into your /locales folder, and edit each of the .po files. Fill in the data for each msgstr. Here is one such example of that:

```
msgid "cîhana hello"
msgstr "Hello world"
```

then you run `./manage.py compilemessages`

and everything will work like a charm

if you need more languages you can go

```
   LANGUAGES = [('en', 'English'), ('ku', 'Kurdish', ('de', 'Deutsch'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('fr', 'French'))]
```

every time you must edit the messages in

```
locale/[language-code]/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

#expect to find something like this

#: templates/index.html:35
msgid "Email"
msgstr "Имейл"
```

Comment: Thanks Kostadin Slavov but Kurdish is not supported from django,there is no po file for kurdish.Wenn i add the  LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ku' and run the manage.py makemessages receive some  error.  raise ValueError('invalid token in plural form: %s' % value)

ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION` is probably caused by an incorrect `Plural-Forms` value in the `.po` header.

Each `.po` file should have a header at the top that looks something like this:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2024-02-26 12:51+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

The `Plural-Forms` tells the translation tools how this particular language pluralises the singular. Specifically how many different ways there are of forming plurals. This is used to generate the correct number of `msgstr` entries for translating strings involving plurals.

The value you have includes the invalid string `EXPRESSION`, which suggests it's just a placeholder and you haven't set the correct plural form.

This webpage lists the plural forms expression for most if not all languages: https://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html

According to the site, the correct value for Kurdish is `nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);`