# Django unsupported language integration

Tags: django, translation

In my django app I want to integrate Armenian language, which is currently unsupported. I have followed all the suggested steps in other links, but I get **ValueError: plural forms expression could be dangerous**. But for example for supported languages like German everything works fine. Please send me a working example.

Comment: How does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su) not answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use django 2.2 there armenian will be supported

[Release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/)

Django 2.2 will release April 2019