# Adding your own language for translation in Django

Tags: python, django

We need to make a translation into the Bashkir language on the site. This does not seem to exist in the locale django file. I'm trying to do this. In the settings.py file added.

```
import django.conf.locale
EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'ba': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'ba',
        'name': 'Bashkir',
        'name_local': 'башкирский'
    },
}
d = django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.copy()
d.update(EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = d


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru' 

LANGUAGES = (
  ('ru', 'Russian'),
  ('en','English'),
  ('ba', 'Bashkir'),
)
```

Now, when following the link, it writes that it cannot find the / ba page.(When switching to ru and en, the translation goes without problems).
I display links on the page as follows.

```
{% for language in languages %}                         
     <a href="/{{ language.code }}/"}>{{ language.code }} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

in urls `+ = i18n_patterns` added. Maybe there is some other way?
Or how to finish the given one?

Comment: have you looked at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su

`LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)`  

`d.update(EXTRA_LANG_INFO)` is the python2 style

Comment: @MichaelLindsay its help me! Thanks