Adding laos language in Django
I have added the langauge laos in settings.py as follows
LANGUAGES = [
    ("en", _("English")),
    ("my", _("Burmese")),
    ("fr", _("French")),
    ("km", _("Khmer")),
    ("th", _("Thai")),
    ("vi", _("Vietnamese")),
    ("lo", _("Lao")),
]

However, when I load my application I get the error.
KeyError at /
'Unknown language code lo.'

Seems like the current version of Django does not support the language.
Is there a way I can manually add a none existing language in Django?
Thank you in-advance.

This post answered my question. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946830/how-to-add-new-languages-into-django-my-language-uyghur-or-uighur-is-not-su
